# Specify default download folder - possibly with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, download

We're currently in the process of developing a web-based application which will require the downloading of files through the browser. It would be ideal to have these files end up in a specific location on the file system.

Is there a way to make the file save and file open dialog default to a specific folder, such as `%USER%\Downloads\MyApp\`?

I don't want it to be a forced thing, but if we can get it to default to the desired location, it would at least be a good prompt for the user, and provide a better experience with other portions of the application.

I'm sure this can be done with a Java control, but it would be nice to be able to do it with some simple JavaScript or something instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, I'm fairly sure this is not possible using JavaScript on any browser.

The only thing you can suggest is the file's name.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it doesn't hurt to ask just in case.  :)

Comment: Does someone know of a browser plugin for chrome or IE that could open access to this feature (despite security flaws) from javascript - preferably filtering by request origin? -Curious as I would like to use this in a intranet web application, and I do not want to embed the existing browser app in an exe if possible.

Comment: @BrianH you said "using JavaScript". Does this mean is it possible with some other language? I have a Java application (JSP) and we want to have a default download directory set for the user to download files (the same also when uploading files)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are developing an App for internal use, you might have some influence on the browser that is used. As of spring 2022, Chrome, Opera, Edge support the **File-System-Access-API** which let you show a **openFilePickerDialog** or a **saveFilePickerDialog** which are independent from the default download location or the last file-upload path of the browser.

Once you have selected a file from the desired folder, this location will be stored in your browser preferences (I guess) and the following calls will directly open to this folder.

Take a look at [this answer for further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70001920/9064287).

As [shown here](https://web.dev/file-system-access/#ask-the-user-to-pick-a-file-to-read), it is then possible to specify in which folder the "file-dialog" should start:

```
const fileHandle = await window.showOpenFilePicker({
  startIn: 'pictures'
});
```

Instead of `pictures`you can specify any "well-known" system folder, or if you program for a well known environment, any path that is likely to be found on the target machines.