# export html table to text file using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, export-to-text

I'm working on a project that requires exporting html table into text file. Below is a simplified version of the HTML code :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Date1</th>
            <th>Date2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
            <td>{{employee.code}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.age}}</td>
            <td><input type="text"  class="datepicker" ng-model="employee.date1"  datepicker /></td>
            <td><input type="text"  class="datepicker" ng-model="employee.date2" datepicker/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The expected outcome should look like this in a text file (with columns aligned nicely):

```
Code   firstName    lastName  Age        Date1         Date2
001       x            y      25      2016/01/01      2016/04/04
...
```

I tried the "classical" way with jquery but it doesnt interpret values inside my td's. So im looking for an angular directive or something like that to overcome such issue. 
Thanks..

Comment: what was problem ???

Comment: here is the problem when i try to export data inside {{ }} :                                                                                                                     ![print screen](http://i.imgur.com/qrkwaKE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty straight forward way to do it would be using the [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

Assuming your table is like this,

```
<table id="demo-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Date1</th>
            <th>Date2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
            <td>{{employee.code}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.age}}</td>
            <td><input type="text"  class="datepicker" ng-model="employee.date1"  datepicker /></td>
            <td><input type="text"  class="datepicker" ng-model="employee.date2" datepicker/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

After this table have been generated, simply invoke the code below,

```
var ele = document.getElementById('demo-table');
var blob = new Blob([ele.innerText], {
        type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
    });
    saveAs(blob, "demo-table.csv");
};
```

For other configurations, check the document of FileSaver.js.

Hope this would solve your problem.

Comment: @Daniel Just replace the innerHTML to innerText, and you need to make sure the table has been generated which means you can invoke this code with `setTimeout`.  Can you post your sample code to jsFiddle?

Comment: Thanks .. Now it works  but it doesnt for Date1 and Date2 column which is normal because they have an input field inside td. Any idea to solve this issue ?

Comment: I think you can try to add `<span style="display: none"> Date 1</span>` into that td to print out the date.

Comment: It prints out when i use 'display : inline' instead of  'display :none ' However i have duplicated value in the same field

Comment: Then you can hide this element in the normal mode, and display this element when user wants to output the table.(e.g. show the span before invoke print func)

Comment: Another solution would be, set the color of the span to white(or your background color). So user cannot see this text, but it can be printed out. Anyway, these are tricky solutions, but easy to implement.

Comment: Than you very much Tyler !

Comment: My pleasure to help. : )

Comment: Can i configure the file where table is downloaded ?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453798/specify-default-download-folder-possibly-with-javascript), this violate user's security policy. So we can only suggest the filename.